# No me corren las animaciones en unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Sucede que tengo una serie de animaciones, correr, bailar y un estado idle, al momento de usar el código para activar dichas acciones después del idle mi avatar intenta generalas pero en su lugar se queda quieto. Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Podrías editar tu pregunta y colocar el código que tienes? puedes guiarte mirando [ask]

Comment: Si añadieras fotos de tu configuración nos serviría de ayuda. Cualquier otra cosa como código o qué formas de solución has probado, también nos sirven. Intenta desarrollar tu pregunta, por favor.